# How to run Packmol

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am biginer in using ubuntu. I have installed packmol in my system which is Ubuntu 14. but I get this error when I run this command:
 command>>>>>>    packmol < packmol.inp 
error>>>>>        packmol: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
./packmol < input.inp
```

Good luck